# R What's the best way to transform multiple variables?

Tags: r, transformation

I've been transforming variables for my data probably a little more difficult than I should. What's a more efficient way to transform batch variables? For example:

```
log_vw = log(msft$vwretd)
log_ew = log(msft$ewretd)
log_sp = log(msft$sprtrn)
log_msft = log(msft$msft)

msft["log_vw"] <- log_vw
msft["log_ew"] <- log_ew
msft["log_sp"] <- log_sp
msft["log_msft"] <- log_msft
head(msft)
```

I've tried using this method, but I receive a few errors along the way..

```
cols <- c("msft$vwretd","msft$ewretd","msft$sprtrn","msft$msft")
df[cols] <- log(cols)
```

In this last example, I am trying to put non-numeric arguments in a mathematical function, so that makes sense.

I understand the *for* statement is the appropriate statement, but am unsure how to structure my command.

Any recommendations would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yep @dayne is right, try something like `cols <- c("vwretd","ewretd","sprtrn","msft"); msft[cols] <- lapply(msft[cols], log)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are a fan of `dplyr`, you could also do,

```
dplyr::mutate_each(msft, funs(log),
                   log_vw = vwretd,
                   log_ew = ewretd,
                   log_sp = sprtrn,
                   log_msft = msft)
```

Output:

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(vwretd = runif(10), ewretd = runif(10), sprtrn = runif(10), msft = runif(10)) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(log), log_vw = vwretd, log_ew = ewretd, log_sp = sprtrn, log_msft = msft)

       vwretd    ewretd     sprtrn        msft     log_vw      log_ew     log_sp   log_msft
1  0.54274693 0.1263857 0.88601706 0.458666312 -0.6111121 -2.06841664 -0.1210191 -0.7794323
2  0.44335175 0.5799405 0.05000435 0.004620247 -0.8133918 -0.54482978 -2.9956452 -5.3773070
3  0.10626751 0.6079891 0.77995001 0.474660813 -2.2417957 -0.49759827 -0.2485255 -0.7451548
4  0.56562366 0.7637879 0.03525097 0.199729556 -0.5698263 -0.26946509 -3.3452623 -1.6107910
5  0.39274678 0.7384458 0.62834120 0.888230976 -0.9345902 -0.30320757 -0.4646719 -0.1185235
6  0.04751128 0.5708233 0.53730398 0.425984998 -3.0467881 -0.56067550 -0.6211913 -0.8533511
7  0.57159055 0.9290444 0.31881544 0.679257606 -0.5593324 -0.07359875 -1.1431429 -0.3867548
8  0.10841133 0.9730511 0.26677617 0.097040692 -2.2218227 -0.02731870 -1.3213453 -2.3326249
9  0.17500813 0.3787455 0.14860983 0.480663703 -1.7429229 -0.97089076 -1.9064310 -0.7325874
10 0.89509921 0.4091091 0.79529002 0.681128521 -0.1108207 -0.89377335 -0.2290484 -0.3840043
```

Comment: I'm installing dplyr right now. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: `mutate_each` will be deprecated. Use `mutate_all` or `mutate_at` instead

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @ dayne and @thelatemail. This does what I need. Thank you.

```
cols <- c("vwretd","ewretd","sprtrn","msft")
msft[cols] <- lapply(msft[cols], log)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(msft)`), specify the 'cols' in `.SDcols`, loop over the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), get the `log` and assign (`:=`) the output to the new columns (`paste0("log_",cols)`).

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("vwretd","ewretd","sprtrn","msft")
setDT(msft)[, paste0("log_", cols) := lapply(.SD, log), .SDcols = cols]
```